# How to get theme screenshot

Tags: themes

I would need to get list of available themes with their screenshot. I tried to use `wp_get_themes` function, but it doesn't seem to be returnig screenshot.

What is the way to get screenshot for each available theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WP_Theme::get_screenshot()` method, which returns the screenshot url.

For example:

```
 $themes = wp_get_themes();
 foreach( $themes as $theme ){
      echo '<img src="'.esc_url($theme->get_screenshot()).'" />';
 }
```

Comment: One more question, which property of the $theme should I pass to `switch_theme()` to switch the theme?

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme, or ask a new question, save burying it in the comments ;)